# How to parse multiple numbers from a column of strings into separate columns

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a regex to match a pattern in a column of a dataframe

Input dataframe:

| coulmn_pattern |
| --- |
| Ate an apple 10x100 num |
| Ate an orange 20x1000ns |
| Good day 20 x 987n |
| Good day 20X 908 n |
| Good day 20 x 1000 ns |
| Good day 250 abs quote |

Output dataframe:

| column_pattern | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ate an apple 10x100 num | 10 | 100 | num |
| Ate an orange 20x1000ns | 20 | 1000 | ns |
| Good day 20 x 987n | 20 | 987 | n |
| Good day 20X 908 n | 20 | 908 | n |
| Good day 20 x 1000 ns | 20 | 1000 | ns |
| Good day 250 abs quote | null | null | null |

Logic here is when `x` or `X` is detected in `column_pattern`, then want to create 3 new columns based on this,

col1 is left part of `x`,
col2 is right part of `x`
col3 is what follows the value after col2's value
Here there may or may not be spaces in between, but it must match the pattern following x or X. Also, the last row is null because it does not have x or X

What I have tried so far: `\d+x\d+.*`, but does not work for all cases.

Comment: You're missing all the optional spacing in your regex. `\d+\s*x\s*\d+\s*\S+` might catch more cases (`\S` for non-space characters, i.e., the unit here).

Comment: If you know for certain the unit is the last item in the string, then append a '$' at the end, to ensure the regex is match only at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `(\d+\.?\d*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(\S+)?` as regex:

```
out = df.join(df['coulmn_pattern']
              .str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*(\S+)?')
              .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Col_{x+1}')
             )
```

Output:

```
            coulmn_pattern Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
0  Ate an apple 10x100 num    10   100   num
1  Ate an orange 20x1000ns    20  1000    ns
2       Good day 20 x 987n    20   987     n
3       Good day 20X 908 n    20   908     n
4    Good day 20 x 1000 ns    20  1000    ns
5   Good day 250 abs quote   NaN   NaN   NaN
6   05 Denmark Aft 70 X 10    70    10   NaN
7               abcd 7x0.5     7   0.5   NaN
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9yUOuW/1)

```
(\d+\.?\d*)  # capture digits with optional decimals
\s*[xX]\s*   # match x or X optionally surrounded by spaces
(\d+\.?\d*)  # capture digits with optional decimals
\s*          # optional spaces
(\S+)?       # capture one or more non-spaces (optionally)
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway, just one more case not working `05 Denmark Aft 70 X 10` `05 Denmark Aft 70X10`, this is not being recognized, any clue on this?

Comment: What should be the output here? There is no unit, do you want to make it optional?

Comment: Yes @mozway, want to make the unit optional, thanks

Comment: Also, `abcd 7x0.5` must be split as `7` and `0.5`, but instead it splits as `7` and `0`, any ways to fix this please? Thanks@mozway

Comment: @Raven see update

Comment: Please edit your question with the appropriate example and expected output

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway, I'm getting a duplicate last column, so the units extracted at the last column is again repeated in another column, I gave this `'(\d+\.?\d*)\s*[xX]\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s*((\S*)?)'` to accommodate optional units

Comment: I slightly changed the regex and provided the output, there is no duplicate column

Comment: Perfect, thanks @mozway, accepted the answer, any ways to rename the dynamic columns 0, 1, 2 with some prefix?

Comment: Yes, `.add_prefix('Col_')` or `.rename(columns=lambda x: f'Col_{x+1}')`

Comment: Thanks @mozway, if I need to parse this `5x1num+5x1mon` as `5`,`1`,`num`,`5`,`1`,`mon` separate columns, then could you please add the regex here as an edit or should I post a new question (any chances of being closed/marked duplicate?)

Comment: @Raven, then the best is to use `extractall` in place of `extract` and this will create a new row, you can always `unstack` afterwards if needed (but this will take more memory)